# While loop not doing anything in the console

Tags: javascript, while-loop

My code is not working so I went to the Chrome console to try and fix it and now that is just returning `undefined` when I try and run my `while` loop.

This is the code I entered into the console:

```
let total = 0;
let playerTotal = 0;

while(total >= 10){
    if (total >= 10){
        if (total > playerTotal){
            console.log('total wins')
        } else if(total == playerTotal){
            console.log('tie')
        } else {
            console.log('player wins')
        }
    }
    total += 1
}
```

Comment: Typo: `total >= 10` should be `total <= 10`.

Comment: Because total is neither greater than nor equal to 10. its 0.
It will work for values Greater than 10 and 10... like 10,11,12,13...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is `while (total >= 10)`. `total` starts out at `0`. `0` is not `>= 10` and so your loop's body is never executed.

You're seeing `undefined` because when you enter code in the console, the final result of that code is displayed. The result of a `while` loop is the value of the last statement evaluated within it ([weird but true](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-while-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation)); a loop that never executes its body therefore results in `undefined`..

Comment: thanks, embarrassing that!

Comment: No worries. I figured it was worth explaining the `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote. This explains OP's problem, and answers the question, I'm rather curious.

Comment: @Hodrobond: It's not important. There are people who downvote answers to questions they think should be closed instead. My view is that the `undefined` aspect of the question makes it *not* a "typo" question, but others disagree, and apparently one disagrees sufficiently to downvote a well-meaning explanation of what's happening.

Comment: Maybe it's because (upvoted) answers on closed questions prevent those closed questions from being deleted. The `undefined` has been explained a bazillion times before on other questions. The typo isn't useful for anyone.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Well, we just disagree that closing the question as a typo and just leaving the OP hanging on why the heck they got `undefined` is a useful thing to do here.

Comment: Maybe link him to a canonical explaining the `undefined`, then. We don't need to "help" every single user that comes with a question, especially not if the question is a typo / duplicate that is of no value to future visitors.

Comment: @Cerbrus you never know what may help a future user or what may hold value in the future

Comment: @Cerbrus Tj Crowders answer helped me, showed me where I went wrong and I learnt something. that seems pretty valuable to me

Answer (score -3):

```
while(total >= 10){
```

should be changed to

```
while(total <= 10){
```

Thats logic issue which trigger infinite loop because total number would not increment since total is 0 and condition of loop only start when total >= 10.